# How to marshal nested structure?

Tags: c#, c++

I have three C++ structures that I need to send as parameters when calling a DLL method from C#.
I simplified them as the following:

```
typedef struct
{
    int data1;
    int data2;
} A;

typedef struct
{
    int numStructA;
    A *pStructA;
    int moreData;
} B;

typedef struct
{
    TCHAR *pStr;
    B structB;
} C;
```

The following is the C++ function I need to call from C#:

```
int func(C *pStructC, int numStructC);
```

In my C# code, I define the structs as the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
private struct A
{
    public int data1;
    public int data2;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
private struct B
{
    public int numStuctA;
    public IntPtr structA;
    public int moreData;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
private struct C
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string Str;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public B structB;
}

[DllImport("somedll.dll")]
private static extern int func(IntPtr pStructC, int size);
```

I tried to marshal the nested structures. However, the C++ function does not receive the data correctly. So far only the data that comes before the nested structure is sent correctly to the C++ function.
How can I marshal the nested structures so the C++ method receives the correct data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove Pack, remove the [MarshalAs] attributes.  The 1st argument of func() should be "ref C".

Comment: Building on Hans's comment, it's typically better to leave the marshaling work to the framework. 98/100 times c# knows how to pack and marshal better than we do, for the most part. Will save you a lot of headache. :)

Comment: Thank you for helping. I removed Pack, removed [MarshalAs] attributes, and changed the 1st argument of func() to 'ref C', I got a System.ArgumentException instead.

Comment: I got some progress. With Pack and MarshalAs attributes removed, I called func() with 'ref structC[0]' as the first parameter. func() was able to receive all structC[0] data correctly. If I call func() with 'ref structC[1]', the data is correctly received also. However, if I call func(ref structC[0], 2), func() can't get struct[1] data. Any ideas?

Comment: I got it working by changing the first parameter to '[In, Out] C[] structC'. Thank you guys for your comments. I really appreciated.